# Actor on stage no longer receives touchDown after libGDX API change

Tags: java, libgdx

I use the latest libGDX builds from the Maven snapshot repository.

My main menu screen class is below. Notice the code which had to be commented out due to API changes in the latest libGDX snapshot.

```java
public class MainMenuScreen implements Screen {

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        stage.setViewport(new ScreenViewport(cam));
        // stage.setViewport(width, height, true); <- Method signature changed
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        stage = new Stage();
        cam = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        cam.position.set(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2, 0);
        cam.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        // stage.setCamera(cam); <- Method no longer exists
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        // Button is an Actor subclass.
        final Button playButton = new Button(Assets.getPlayButtonTexture(), positions.playOut);
        stage.addActor(playButton);
        playButton.addListener(new InputListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                // This event no longer fires when I tap playButton!
            }
        });
    }

    // ...

    private Stage stage;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private OrthographicCamera cam;
}
```

As you can see from the comment in `touchDown`, that event is no longer being fired.

What part of my code do I need to change to allow the `playButton` actor to receive `touchDown` events as it did before the recent libGDX change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```java
stage = new Stage();
stage.setCamera(cam);
```

becomes

```java
stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport(cam));
```

and

```java
stage.setViewport(width, height, true);
```

becomes

```java
stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
```

Comment: The changes are explained in more detail here: http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3322

Comment: Thanks, I missed that.